# why html form submit button not working on android mobiles but working in pc?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, button

Why is it that, when I click on the `Send Message` button (in the form) on the browser using my PC, my default mail app opens. But when I click on the same button on my android phone then none of the apps open / are prompted to open.

```
<form action="mailto:example@mail.com" method="post" role="form" class="email-form">

<!--
<div class="form-row">
      
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
</div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />

</div>

<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
</div>

-->

<div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
</form>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Is there any alternative code in HTML or say js/jquery to open the mail app to send the mail when I click on the submit/send message button in form?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=mailto%3A

Comment: `android != pc`